# How to fix 'duplicate key issue of mongodb' after the version upgrade of other dependent projects in pom.xml

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I updated the version of the dependent project to the newer one in my project. Now the tomcat doesn't start itself.

It is a spring boot application. I updated the version of the dependent project to the newer one in my project. Now when I run from embedded tomcat from eclipse, it works fine. But when I copy past the war in my webapps folder of tomcat, it doesn't start from tomcat.

Actual: Application starting from Eclipse and not from tomcat.

Expected: Application should start from tomcat and Eclipse both.

Answer (score 0):

when we open the dependency hierarchy in pom.xml, we see some duplicate jars. Exlipse takes care of the conflicted jars, though tomcat is not able to. So I checked the classes, exactly which version the jar was used in eclipse. Kept only those and excluded or commented the other conflicting mongo dependency. And it worked.